# Is there a way to highlight the clicked mat-tab? When each mat-tab is dynamically generated

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, angular6

I'm dynamically showing mat-tabs in the UI whose number and data varies as their values changes in the back end. They're dynamically generated. A Click on any one `mat-tab` invokes a function and passes an ID to it to proceed. I want to identify the mat-tab which has been clicked and keep it highlighted until the user is routed to another page.

I've tried `mat-tab:active{background-color: #333}` which didn't worked

```
    <mat-tab-group [selectedIndex]="Index" (selectedTabChange)="tabChanged($event)" style="width:100%" #Tabgroup>
          <div *ngFor="let item of items; let last = last;" class="button">
            <mat-tab>
              <ng-template mat-tab-label>
                <span class="XYZ" id="item.Id"
                  (click)="setmodule(item.Id)">{{item.Name}}</span>
              </ng-template>
            </mat-tab>
          </div>
    </mat-tab-group>
```

No error messages! But the requirement isn't fulfilled.

Answer (score 1):

You should store clicked tab id in a variable and then use ngClass like this :

```
<mat-tab-group [selectedIndex]="Index" (selectedTabChange)="tabChanged($event)" style="width:100%" #Tabgroup>
      <div *ngFor="let item of items; let last = last;" class="button">
        <mat-tab [ngClass]="{'tab-selected': selectedTabId==item.id}">
          <ng-template mat-tab-label>
            <span class="XYZ" id="item.Id"
              (click)="setmodule(item.Id)">{{item.Name}}</span>
          </ng-template>
        </mat-tab>
      </div>
</mat-tab-group>
```

In your styles :

```
.tab-selected
{
  background-color: #333;
  // Some styles
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set background-color property to the "**mat-tab-label-active**" class which is set automatically when a particular tab becomes active.

This class can be accessed using ng-deep like:

```
::ng-deep .mat-tab-label-active {
  background-color: #333;
}
```

However if you have mat-tab on other components too, it will affect the styling of all the components with mat-tab. To avoid this, you can assign a class to your mat-tab-group and access the mat-tab-label-active class using it like below:

```
<mat-tab-group class="menu-tab" [(selectedIndex)]="selectedTabIndex">
  <div *ngFor="let item of menuList">
  <mat-tab>
    <ng-template mat-tab-label>
      <a class="side-nav-link">{{ item.value}}</a>
    </ng-template>
  </mat-tab>
</div>
</mat-tab-group>
```

In the styles -

```
.menu-tab ::ng-deep .mat-tab-label-active {
  background-color: #333;
}
```